# How to loop through this JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have this JSON from a controller.

Controller:

```
$data = array ('pks_h' => $data_pks, 'pks_d' => $data_pks_d);
echo json_encode($data);
```

JQuery:

```
success     : function(data){
        $('#name').val(data.pks_h[0]['name']);

        alert(JSON.stringify(data.pks_d));
        //[{"no":"1","nomor":"19/0048-PKS/SCG-PM1","id_object":"B001","jumlah":"6000000","jumlah_sisa":"6000000","harga":"150","status":"1"},{"no":"2","nomor":"19/0048-PKS/SCG-PM1","id_object":"B009","jumlah":"15000000","jumlah_sisa":"15000000","harga":"200","status":"1"},{"no":"3","nomor":"19/0048-PKS/SCG-PM1","id_object":"B020","jumlah":"10000000","jumlah_sisa":"10000000","harga":"250","status":"1"}]

        $.each(data.pks_d, function(i, response){ alert(response.harga); });
    }
```

Why the `alert(response.harga);` is not working?? However the script to inserting data to textbox is working.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (I get alerts of 150, 200, 250). Maybe data.pks_d is not what you think it is, or perhaps your browser is blocking the additional alerts?

```js
var data = {};
   data.pks_d = [{"no":"1","nomor":"19/0048-PKS/SCG-PM1","id_object":"B001","jumlah":"6000000","jumlah_sisa":"6000000","harga":"150","status":"1"},{"no":"2","nomor":"19/0048-PKS/SCG-PM1","id_object":"B009","jumlah":"15000000","jumlah_sisa":"15000000","harga":"200","status":"1"},{"no":"3","nomor":"19/0048-PKS/SCG-PM1","id_object":"B020","jumlah":"10000000","jumlah_sisa":"10000000","harga":"250","status":"1"}];

   $.each(data.pks_d, function(i, response){ alert(response.harga); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```